# How to make Orion Context Broker works with HTTPS notification?

Tags: ssl, https, fiware, fiware-orion

I want to enable https for notifications. The Orion Context Broker version 1.7.0 is installed in Ubuntu 16.04. To start, the following command is being used:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/contextBroker start -logAppend -https -key /path/to/orion.key -cert /path/to/orion.crt
```

The answer is:

```
[ ok ] Starting contextBroker (via systemctl): contextBroker.service.
```

The status is:

```
sudo systemctl status contextBroker.service
contextBroker.service - LSB: Example initscript
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/contextBroker; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-04-04 12:56:13 BRT; 14s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 8312 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/contextBroker start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Apr 04 12:56:13 fiware-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB:  Example initscript...
Apr 04 12:56:13 fiware-ubuntu contextBroker[8312]: contextBroker
Apr 04 12:56:13 fiware-ubuntu contextBroker[8312]: /path/bin/contextBroker
Apr 04 12:56:13 fiware-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Example initscript.
```

Another approach is running Orion as:

```
sudo /path/bin/contextBroker -logLevel DEBUG -localIp x.y.z.t -https -key /path/to/orion.key -cert /path/to/orion.crt
```

The log follows:

```
time=2017-04-04T18:37:58.881Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[1705]:main | msg=Orion Context Broker is running
time=2017-04-04T18:37:58.887Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[205]:mongoConnect | msg=Successful connection to database
time=2017-04-04T18:37:58.887Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[681]:setWriteConcern | msg=Database Operation Successful (setWriteConcern: 1)
time=2017-04-04T18:37:58.887Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[724]:getWriteConcern | msg=Database Operation Successful (getWriteConcern)
time=2017-04-04T18:37:58.888Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[626]:runCollectionCommand | msg=Database Operation Successful (command: { buildinfo: 1 })
...
time=2017-04-04T18:37:58.897Z | lvl=FATAL | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=rest.cpp[1720]:restStart | msg=Fatal Error (error starting REST interface)
```

It is not working...

Answer (score 0):

If you run Orion as a service (as recommended) then command line parameters have to be configured in the `/etc/sysconfig/contexBroker` file. The file is explained in [this piece of documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/running/index.html#configuration-file).

Note the `BROKER_EXTRA_OPS` variable at the end of the file. This is used to include CLI parameters that are not set using any other option, as the ones related with HTTPS you are using. Thus, it should be a matter of setting `BROKER_EXTRA_OPS` in this way:

```
BROKER_EXTRA_OPS="-logAppend -https -key /path/to/orion.key -cert /path/to/orion.crt"
```

Then start the service using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/contextBroker start
```

(Note that no parameter is added after 'start')

You can check that Orion is running with the right parameters using `ps ax | grep contextBroker`.

Finally, regarding the error `Fatal Error (error starting REST interface)` it apperas when Orion, for some reason, is not able to start the listening server for the REST API. Typically this is due to some other process (maybe a forgotten instance of Orion) runs listening at the same port. Use `sudo netstat -ntpld | grep 1026` to know which other process could be listening at that part (assuming that 1026 is the port in which you are trying to run Orion, of course).

Comment: We tried like you said, but the problem continues. The contextBroker does not start. The error persists and the port 1026 (default) is not being used by some other process. Any other thing we can do?

Comment: @fgalan. is there a specific reason to redirect the logs to `/dev/null` in the function that starts the daemon/service?

Comment: @Matteus Sthefano, it order to keep topics separate, could you post that question in an independent post at StackOverflow, please? Include "fiware-orion" label, please. Thanks!

Comment: @Dalton, I have just realized that you are running Orion in Ubuntu, so I'm not sure if the /etc/sysconfig/contextBroker + /etc/init.d/contextBroker will work (as they are prepared for CentOS 6.x)... Thus, let's try a simpler test: 1) ensure no Orion process is running (use `ps ax | grep contextBroker` and kill them is someone appear), 2) Run ContextBroker in foreground and see what it happens, using: `contextBroker -https -key /path/to/orion.key -cert /path/to/orion.crt -fg`. Please, update your question post with the result of this test. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @fgalan . I'd already done this test and the result already was in the question, where I said " Another approach is running Orion as:".
The result is  `time=2017-04-10T20:16:36.876Z | lvl=FATAL | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=rest.cpp[1720]:restStart | msg=Fatal Error (error starting REST interface)`
Anything else we can do?

Comment: The command you show just after "Another approach is running Orion as" is not exaclty the same I propose. In particular, you add `-localIp x.y.z.t`. Try to run *without* that `-localIp` parameter. If that doesn't work, try to run without `-https`, `-key` and `-cert` in order to see if at least the basic Orion starting (i.e. without HTTPS) works.

Comment: You are right, @fgalan . I forgot to mention in my last comment that we also tried as you said (without -localIp). But the message is the same. The basic Orion starting is running without problems (without the https parameters). Any other thing we can try? Thanks.

Comment: How did you generate the .key and .crt files?

Comment: Using OpenSSL, @fgalan .

Comment: Could you try to generate .key and .crt files using the https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/test/functionalTest/httpsPrepare.sh script, please? At the end, that scripts also uses openssl internally, but with a particular parametrization that at least in my case has worked. Just to know if this could be a cause of the problem...

Comment: I do not think this can be the cause, but surely we can do this test. :)

Comment: @fgalan , as expected, the problem continues. We used your script to create key and crt files. Nothing changed.

Comment: Could you do the same test using a CentOS 6.x system with the official RPM, please? Just to discard the distro (Ubuntu) or the building procedure (I understand you compiled Orion from source) as possible causes of the problem (maybe due to some underlying library version or building configuration difference). Thanks!

Comment: Any news on this, @Dalton?

Comment: Hello, @fgalan . I tried here, configuring the /etc/sysconfig/contexBroker file as you mentioned, in the CentOS VM, but the Orion does not start. I used this config: `BROKER_EXTRA_OPS="-logAppend -https -key /path/to/orion_key.priv -cert /path/to/orion_cert.der"` . I don't think the file extension is a problem if the format is correct, right?

Comment: Quick test: have you tried to remane your file from .der to .cert in order to see if it works?